# Can select() return 1 yet FD_ISSET(fd) be false?

Tags: c++, select, tcp, file-descriptor

I ran into a situation where I was calling `select()` with a single file descriptor in the set passed, in my C++ application on a TCP socket and it returned `1`, very soon after that in the code, `select()` was called again and either it returned `0` or `FD_ISSET()` on the descriptor was `false` (not sure which and I cannot easily reproduce this rare condition).  Therefore, I'm wondering, can `select()` go from returning `1` to `0` on the same file descriptor if nothing has been read from the descriptor between the two calls, in which case what is going on when that occurs?  Or if not, then can `select()` return `1`, yet `FD_ISSET()` be `false`, even though only one file descriptor was passed to `select()`, in which case, what is going on when that occurs?

Answer (score 1):

`select()` can modify the `fd_set` items that you give it, so make sure that you reset the `fd_set` items *every time* you call `select()`.

That being said, let's assume that you are passing the socket in the *read* fd_set parameter.  The first time `select()` is called and the socket is readable, the socket will remain in the `fd_set`, and `select()` will return 1.  As long as the socket remains readable, `select()` will happily keep the socket in the `fd_set`.  However, if `select()` returns 0, that means `select()` timed out (the socket was not readable within a specified timeframe), and so `select()` will remove the socket from the `fd_set` and `FD_ISSET()` will be false.  Thus the need to reset the `fd_set` on the next call to `select()` to put the socket back into the `fd_set` so it can be tested again.

Now, regarding why and how your socket/fd_set could be going from a readable state to a non-readable state, that is difficult to answer without seeing your actual code that is managing the socket and populating the `fd_set` on each `select()` call.  My guess is that either you are not managing them correctly to begin with, or you have multiple threads that are sharing the socket/fd_set and trampling over each other's states in a manner you are not expecting.